# Cauchy Integral Formula for $1/z+1/z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

From *Cauchy's Integral Formula*, we can define $f\left(z\right) = z^{2} + z$, and find for any contour $C$ on the right part of the semi-plane $\Re\left(z\right) > 0$ that
\begin{align*}
\int_{C}\left(\frac{1}{z} +
\frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)\mathrm{d}z & =
\int_{C}\frac{z^{2} + z}{z^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}z =
\int_{C}\frac{f\left(z\right)}
{\left(z - 0\right)^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}z =
\pi\mathrm{i}f''\left(0\right) =
2\pi\mathrm{i}
\end{align*}

This should work since $z\not= 0$ because $\Re\left(z\right)>0$. However, if I want to calculate

\begin{align*}
\int_{1 - \mathrm{i}}^{1 + \,\sqrt{\,{3}\,}\,\mathrm{i}}
\left(\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)\mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}

Would the two integrals have the same value if the path intersect both points $?$. Or in the definite integral would be necessary to just integrate as the usual $?$.

Comment: Why did you write the integrand as $(z^2+z)/z^3$ rather than $(z+1)/z^2$?

Comment: Right, I think I just did it rushing my procedure. However, we would end up with $4z\pi i$ if we use the Cauchy formula.

Comment: $4z\pi i$? You don't want a $z$-dependent answer.

Comment: @J.G. sorry, it would be first derivative, which would be $f'(z)=1$, so the answer still holds as $2\pi i$, thank you

Answer (score -1):

In Cauchy's Integral Formula, the contour $C$ is the boundary of a disk in the complex plane that contains the singularity of the integrand.  So, in the example here, we have

$$\oint_C \left(\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}\right)\,dz=2\pi i$$

if $z=0$ is interior to the disk bounded by $C$.

If $C$ is not the boundary of any disk for which $z=0$ is an interior point, then Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that the integral over $C$ is $0$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?  How is this not useful?